# RxJava Observable based on items on a list

Tags: android, rx-java

I need an Observable that never ends, and just process some data and chain another observable when there are items on a list. Is there any way of accomplish that, and what would be the best approach=?

My closest idea was to create a timer observable and check every x seconds if there are items on the list. This idea is not ideal, because i need to process the data as soon as there are values on that list, which i modify outside the observable chain.

```
return Observable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap(integer -> captureList.getLatestCaptureCut())
                .flatMap(vp::processVideo)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .repeat()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html), and push your next items there.

```
PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.<Integer>create();

subject.flatMap(integer -> captureList.getLatestCaptureCut())
    .flatMap(vp::processVideo)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe();

//push new items
subject.onNext(0);
subject.onNext(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a `PublishSubject` in your `CaptureList` class. Instead of providing a *pull* method `getLatestCaptureCut()`, you could provide a *push* method, with a Subject:

```
PublishSubject<VP> captured = PublishSubject.create();
```

You could then `.subscribe()` to the `PublishSubject` and process the data when they come in.

In your `CaptureList` you would call

```
captured.onNext(vp);
```

every time new data is available. For instance, in your `setLatestCaptureCut()`. I'm assuming you already have some kind of routine that generates the `CaptureCut` and store it, to make it available in `getLatestCaptureCut()`.